# Debouncing Google Maps Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Good day.

Right now I'm using google maps to autocomplete addresses on my service. 
This is the code:

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('address_field')),
    {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
    }
);
```

And as I type, it pings the google server for suggestions.
These pings are taking up a lot of tokens.

So I'm thinking - is there a way to debounce the request?

I tried debouncing it with the debounce library, but that obviously doesn't work.
Also tried adding a delay:300 to the options object, still nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Edit**: After the changes to Google Maps's pricing in May 2019. You do not longer pay per request, but rather per autocomplete session. It doesn't matter how many search queries the user types in, they all will still be counted as one session. 
Thus making this question moot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of now, Google Maps Autocomplete does not support debounce on API call. Though an issue related to this has been already registered.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5831

Comment: Also is a good idea to star the issue to let Google know that we really appreciate this feature request. Currently only 7 stars, not too much.

Answer (score 2):

You can customize Google map autocomplete component with [Retrieving Autocomplete Predictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction) and [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details)

Here is a simple demo with React.[Custom Google Map Autocomplete](https://jsfiddle.net/sheldonyu/4aq7y3o8/)

Hope this can help you, thanks.

```
const handleSearch = () => {
  autocompleteService.getPlacePredictions(
  {
    input: text,
    origin: latLng,
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: "NG", // country: string | string[];
    }
  }, handleSuggestions);
}
```